How to unbind some columns from PDO prepare statement
Let's say I have a regular prepare statement, but sometimes I must omit some columns from being updated:
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET price = ?, size = ?, color = ? 
                        WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");`

In most cases the execution would be like this:
$stmt->execute([ $price, $size, $color, $id ]);

But in some cases I have to omit some columns from being changed.
For example:
if( $size == 0 ) {
    // in this case I must omit the size column and keep the current value 
    ///in the database. I don't need the zero in there
}

Any smart ways of including/removing columns for the query?

Build the query dynamically based on what you want to do at this particular time

Build the query dynamically based on what you want to do at any particular time
if ( $IdontneedSize ) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table 
                            SET price = ?, color = ? 
                        WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute([ $price, $color, $id ]);
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table 
                            SET price = ?, size = ?, color = ? 
                        WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute([ $price, $size, $color, $id ]);
}

It does not need to be any more complicated that this.
In response to your comments. Do you mean something like this?
You could do all the prepares first, giving them sensible names
$NoSize = $db->prepare("UPDATE table 
                        SET price = ?, color = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$allThree= $db->prepare("UPDATE table 
                        SET price = ?, size = ?, color = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");

if ( $size = 0 ) {
    $NoSize->execute([ $price, $color, $id ]);
} else {
    $allThree->execute([ $price, $size, $color, $id ]);
}

However, if you never actually use the NoSize senario you have wasted a server round trip to compile and optimise a query you will never use.

That would be quite a bunch of code if I had lots of conditions. Maybe there is a better way. Hmm...

Well there is no way to Un-Bind a column from a query. When yuo run the prepare, you have basically sent a query to the server for compilation and optimisation. You then pass this precompiled query parameter for it to be run with. You have to repeat the compile and optimise steps (prepare) in order to change the query

Flexibility almost always involves more code

I'm wondering how about using named placeholders... Would it help somehow or not...

Do you mean like size = :size instead of size = ? That would not help you in any way

Yes, exactly. Maybe there is a way to build the actual prepare query first and then build the execute params for it (with no writing the full same prepare statement always). Sorry if I'm writing nuts here.
